# Scroll specific section using jQuery Mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, mousewheel

I want to make this scrolling effect (link: http://nicolas-bussiere.com/) but I have no idea how to do that.

I am new to jQuery so it is so difficult for me to understand the complex code which the website is using. I tried to make the scrolling with Mousewheel plugin but I can never understand.

Here is my website -> http://heeyounhong.com/

I have three sections which are "intro", "about" and "works".
In the "works" section, I have 8 different projects.

---

On the right side, I have each illustration like the below.

```html
<!-- ** PROJECTS : RIGHT ** -->
<div class="content illustrations-container">
    <ul class="illustrations">
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
        <li class="illustration"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1. I want to add class "animated" on "ul" when I scroll the section and add a style like the below.

```css
first scrolling > "transform: translateY(-100%) translateZ(0px);"
second scrolling > "transform: translateY(-200%) translateZ(0px);"
third scrolling > "transform: translateY(-300%) translateZ(0px);"
```

---

On the left side, I have 8 "line" divs like the below.

```html
<!-- ** PROJECTS : LEFT ** -->
<div class="lines title">
  <div class="line proj line-proj1"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj2"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj3"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj4"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj5"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj6"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj7"></div>
  <div class="line proj line-proj8"></div>
</div>
```

2. I want to add class ".before" ".after" ".going-up" ".going-down" ".current" on each "line" div.

I know my explanation is rough but I can't write all the codes I have written.

I refer to the code from the website I did benchmarking and put most classes I need for the scrolling effect on my style sheet (style.css).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In addition, the adding of begging messages in your title is akin to vandalism, which creates more work for a volunteer editor.

Comment: Sorry, new to SO any chance you can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 2 things, first mousewheel event:

```
$('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            console.log('scrolling up !');
        }
        else{
            console.log('scrolling down !');
        }
    });
```

then you will need to track which div is visible in the viewport

```
function inViewport (el) {

    var r, html;
    if ( !el || 1 !== el.nodeType ) { return false; }
    html = document.documentElement;
    r = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return ( !!r 
      && r.bottom >= 0 
      && r.right >= 0 
      && r.top <= html.clientHeight 
      && r.left <= html.clientWidth 
    );
}
```

Then once you have the element you are in viewport you can select the element up or down and scroll to it.